what if there is prior art passingly mentioning the abstract idea of your invention?
So you are trying to patent an invention that implements a concrete version of an abstract idea.
What if the abstract idea is mentioned here and there in the prior art?

Abstract ideas are not (or at least should not be) patentable. Implementations may be.

@EricS Strictly speaking that's true; I kind of assumed OP meant "overarching idea" rather than strictly abstract idea.


What if the abstract idea is mentioned here and there in the prior art?

Well, does the invention lie in the abstract idea that is now considered old and known or the implementation of it?
If the former, tough luck. The examiner will usually be able to form a solid rejection by combining the art that shows the abstract idea with additional art that shows the implementative bits that form the claim.
However many inventions are known as an "abstract idea" before someone invents a particularly useful implementation, which may then be patentable to them. For example, television was very obvious as a goal long before it was realized in practice.
